# Integration + Differentiation

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble with the following question.

If $F(x)=\int_{0}^x xf(t) dt$, find F'(x).

Please help

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, notice first that you can pull $x$ out of the integral. Then, you can use the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus to obtain the answer. Remember that $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\int_{0}^x f(t)\text{d}t=f(x).$$

Comment: I get $F'(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt +x(f(x)-f(0))$

Comment: Why is f(0)=0 ?

Comment: @user43418 let's say that we have $G(t)=\int f(t) dt$, so $\int_0^x f(t) dt=G(x)-G(0)$. When you take the derivative the constant term drops out, and you're left with $G'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: So $F'(x)= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+xf(x)$

Comment: Is that correct ?